# Swap Google Doc images with new images from Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a Google Doc with images (let's say 4 but in reality there are many). I want to replace those with four new images available in Google Drive. I know I can get all images available in the Doc as:

```
var images = docFile.getBody().getImages();
```

All are `InlineImage` when displayed on the console, although a few are in the paragraph and others are inside table cells. The logic I have in my mind is:

- Getting the list of images (as done above)
- Getting the location of those images (Don't know how)
- Delete the image and use `appendImage` method.

The exact code I tried is:

```
function imageExtract() {
  const tempFile = DocumentApp.openById(idOfFile) //idOfFile is id of Doc file
  var images = tempFile.getBody().getImages();

  const blob=DriveApp.getFileById(idOfImage)     //idOfImage is id of Doc file
  
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    Logger.log(images[i].getAttributes())
    Logger.log(images[i])
    // Here I want to delete the images[i]
    // And put blob there 
  }

}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to replace those with four new images available in Google Drive.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike The Doc has 4 images. I want those to be deleted and replaced with the 4 present in my GDrive.

Comment: @Rubén It was a lengthy code so I pasted just one line. Anyways now I have added one brief code for further clarity. Please see now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `The Doc has 4 images. I want those to be deleted and replaced with the 4 present in my GDrive.`, in this case, how should we correspond to 4 images in Google Document with 4 images in Google Drive?

Comment: @Tanaike I have 4 links for 4 images in GDrive. So in GDoc I will delete the first image and will place the GDrive image link1. Then delete the second image from GDoc and will place the GDrive image link2 and so on. Of course, I will automate this with a `for` loop but that I can handle. I need help on deleting image from GDoc and placing a new image (from GDrive Link) there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstodo your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- Your Google Document has 4 images. The images are put into the paragraph, list, and table.
- You have a list including 4 URLs of the direct links of image data.
- You want to replace 1st image in Google Document with the 1st URL of the list.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I thought that in this case, when Google Docs API is used, the script might be simple. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This script uses Google Docs API. So, [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set your 4 URLs.
  const urls = [
    "https://url1",
    "https://url2",
    "https://url3",
    "https://url4",
  ];

  // Retrieve the original title of images and set the unique image titles using Docs API.
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const images = doc.getBody().getImages();
  const titles = images.reduce((m, e, i) => {
    const org = e.getAltTitle();
    e.setAltTitle(`sample${i}`);
    m.set(`sample${i}`, { title: org, uri: urls[i] });
    return m;
  }, new Map());
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Create request body of Docs API.
  const { inlineObjects } = Docs.Documents.get(doc.getId(), { fields: "inlineObjects" });
  const requests = Object.entries(inlineObjects).reduce((ar, [imageObjectId, { inlineObjectProperties: { embeddedObject } }]) => {
    if (embeddedObject.hasOwnProperty("imageProperties")) {
      const { uri } = titles.get(embeddedObject.title);
      ar.push({ replaceImage: { imageObjectId, uri } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Request Docs API using the created request body.
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());

  // Set the original titles to the images.
  const ar = [...titles];
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getImages().forEach((e, i) => e.setAltTitle(ar[i][1].title));
}
```

- When this script is run, 4 images in Google Document are replaced with the images of 4 URLs.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#replaceimagerequest)

### Added:

I think that your provided sample Document and your provided current script have 2 issues.

1. When I saw your sample Document, I saw 4 images. But, when I retrieve the images using Google Docs API, 5 images are existing. It seems that one image is not shown. Unfortunately, the reason for `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'uri' of 'titles.get(...)' as it is undefined.` is due to this.

   - From this situation, in my added sample script, the unshown images are ignored. By this, this error is avoided.
2. I had thought that you have a list including 4 URLs of the direct links of image data. But, unfortunately, when I saw your provided script, the URLs are not the direct link like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}`. In this case, an error occurs when Docs API is requested. I think that this will be your 2nd issue.

When these points are reflected in my proposed sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

In this sample, Google Docs API and Google Drive API are used. So, please enable Docs API and Drive API at Advanced Google services.

And, please set the file IDs of the image file on your Google Drive. The file ID is `###` of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###`. Please be careful about this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Please set the file IDs of the images in your Google Drive.
  const fileIds = [
    "### file ID 1 ###",
    "### file ID 2 ###",
    "### file ID 3 ###",
    "### file ID 4 ###",
  ];

  // Create direct links of the images.
  const urls = fileIds.map(id => Drive.Files.get(id).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s512"));

  // Retrieve the original title of images and set the unique image titles using Docs API.
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const images = doc.getBody().getImages();
  const titles = images.reduce((m, e, i) => {
    const org = e.getAltTitle();
    e.setAltTitle(`sample${i}`);
    m.set(`sample${i}`, { title: org, uri: urls[i] });
    return m;
  }, new Map());
  doc.saveAndClose();

  // Create request body of Docs API.
  const { inlineObjects } = Docs.Documents.get(doc.getId(), { fields: "inlineObjects" });
  const requests = Object.entries(inlineObjects).reduce((ar, [imageObjectId, { inlineObjectProperties: { embeddedObject } }]) => {
    if (embeddedObject.hasOwnProperty("imageProperties") && embeddedObject.title) {
      const { uri } = titles.get(embeddedObject.title);
      ar.push({ replaceImage: { imageObjectId, uri } });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Request Docs API using the created request body.
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, doc.getId());

  // Set the original titles to the images.
  const ar = [...titles];
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getImages().forEach((e, i) => e.setAltTitle(ar[i][1].title));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am getting this error:

>  
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'uri' of 'titles.get(...)' as it is undefined.
(anonymous) @ fromSOF.gs:25
myFunction @ fromSOF.gs:23

Comment: I guess your answer is quite close to what I need. Please guide on resolving the above error.

Comment: @ahsan naeem Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'uri' of 'titles.get(...)' as it is undefined.`, can you provide the detailed information for correctly replicating your issue? Because when I tested my script, no error occurs. The reason that no error occurs is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. In this case, it is required to correctly know your situation. By replicating your current issue, I would like to think of a modification. I would like to support you.

Comment: @ahsan naeem For example, in order to correctly understand your `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'uri' of 'titles.get(...)' as it is undefined.`, can you provide the simple sample Google Document including the script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @ahsan naeem From your provided sample Document and your provided current script, I modified my proposed sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks but now it created another error on line number 35 although the GDrive link for the image is Public. This is the error:

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].replaceImage: There was a problem retrieving the image. The provided image should be publicly accessible, within size limit, and in supported formats

Comment: @ahsan naeem Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your reply, my proposed script converts the image file to the published dynamic link as you can see. And, when I tested my proposed script using your provided Document, no error occurs. So, I cannot understand your current situation, this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill and I have to study more.

Comment: @ahsan naeem In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @ahsan naeem Although I have tested my proposed script several times using your provided sample Document, unfortunately, my script worked fine with no errors. This is due to my very poor skill. I really apologize for my very poor skill again. In this case, as the same with your 1st issue, it is required to replicate correctly your current issue of `error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to docs.documents.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].replaceImage`. I deeply apologize for my very very poor skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my very poor skill.